# Automatic Advanced styling for QGIS

Tags: python-2.7, styling, qgis

I have a PostGIS database containing roads, waterbodies. POI, parks, etc that I have styled in QGIS following the very useful posts: [Guide to Advanced Labeling for OSM Roads](https://anitagraser.com/2011/09/13/guide-to-advanced-labeling-for-osm-roads/) and [“Google Maps”-Style Road Maps in QGIS](https://anitagraser.com/2011/09/16/google-maps-styled-road-maps-in-qgis/) of Anita Grasser.

I'm a python programmer and I would like to recreate these styles automatically not by hand, is it possible? Could anyone show me any example?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In QGIS You can get labeling in command line choose layer and type

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.labelling()
```

You will get instance of QgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling
https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Abstract/QgsAbstractVectorLayerLabeling.html?highlight=qgsabstractvectorlayerlabeling

To go to symbol You need type

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.renderer()
```

You will get class QgsFeatureRenderer https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Feature/QgsFeatureRenderer.html?highlight=qgsfeaturerenderer#qgis.core.QgsFeatureRenderer.symbols

You can also set renderer by

```
renderer = QgsFeatureRenderer() 
layer.setRenderer(renderer)
```